# Adding location services to GPS app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, gps, location

How to add location services to a GPS app I'm making in Xcode Current IDE version is 6.4. I'm very new to swift and IOS development in general.

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: There is the Apple Document "Location Awareness Guide", It describes exactly your question

Comment: Thanks guys, i've fairly new at coding let alone this new swift language.